# python multiprocessing google compute engine

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, google-compute-engine

I have a python script which I run on my old quad-core laptop through multiprocessing. The simulation cannot be parallelised, I just run different instances of it on the different cores.

I was considering renting some more powerful cpus on google compute engine. Will I be able to use the same python multiprocessing script just with more cores available?

the script just calls a pool and then apply_async many times

Comment: yes, you could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiprocessing works the same way on Google's VMs as on your local box (roughly...). In order to use all cores available on a box, do not pass `processes` argument to `multiprocesing.Pool`, like:

```
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=None)
```

This will make Python create a `Pool` with `multiprocessing.cpu_count()` number of processes, `cpu_count` *usually* being a  number of cores.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it should be possible. If you need access to multiple cores on the same instance, as an example the App Engine [flexible runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/), which uses Compute Engine as the underlying VM,  allows you to [configure the number of cores available](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#resource-settings)